# Crystal reports shifted headers

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I'M new newbie to crystal report and I'M having problems with deploying crystal reports to the production server.

This is a snap shoot to what is happening on the production server the headers and table's first rows are shifted down.

[image: This is a snap shoot to what is happening on the production server]
Any idea how to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this response on another site:

This is actually a Crystal Reports bug which affects **13.0.4** Version.
Iit **works fine when you run the same report using the 13.0.3** (and probably earlier) version.

This bug is known to the CR team and they are going to solve it: http://scn.sap.com/thread/3207181

[Look here](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824), you can download actual and previous versions of runtime.